# Does tDOM have the equivalent of the CSS ^= operator?

Tags: xpath, tcl, tdom

Is there a method of selecting elements with a class attribute that is similar to the `[class^="nm_"]` used in CSS? I'd like to return all the spans that have a class that begins with `nm_`. The `^=` is not recognized in tDOM.

`foreach item [$doc selectNodes {html/body/div[@class="main"]//span[@class^="nm_"]}] {`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use function `starts-with`:

```
//span[starts-with(@class, "nm_")]
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know where there is documentation for these types of functions? Is it standard `XPath` or a `tDOM` specific item?

Comment: @Gary I'm quite sure that `tDOM` uses standard XPath features. You can find list of functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions). Note that there are XPath versions 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.1 with different sets of supported functions. However most tools still uses XPath 1.0 only. You can also check good [XPath tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)